# Why AJAX POST request failed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have simple a html page with form. When I do POST request then receive failed, but it not response from server. What I do wrong?

```
function createRequest(url, body) {
    var response;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body)); // (1)
    $.ajax({
        url: "creation/" + url,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(body),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == true) {
                response = data.response;
            } else {
                BootstrapDialog.show({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: data.errorMessage
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return response;
}
```

Body (1)

```
{"name":"Test UI","bid":"2","budget":"20"}
```

When I do this request via POSTMAN all work fine.

[jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js)

Error appaear in Chroome Version 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit), but in Edge all works fine
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with adding a datatype in the ajax request? `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: I tried, in console additional appear error message:

_Uncaught ReferenceError: postAjax is not defined
    at createCampaign (create:217)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (create:106)_

Comment: do u you have a function named `postAjax` ? @BogdanK

Comment: Yes, I remove already this function, but `postAjax` executed after ajax request - it not related errors

Comment: @BogdanK thats why you have that error

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal why? i don't understand

Comment: @BogdanK You are calling a function that didn't exist

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: postAjax is not defined at createCampaign (create:217) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (create:106) ` this error is telling you that you tried to click on an html button which calls a method called `postAjax()`, but there is no such method in your code.

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal, i remove `postAjax` and error not appear again, but problem with ajax request still reproduce

Comment: @BogdanK just to confirm, is the success callback called? i.e. if you put debug inside the success callback is it triggered, if not, try adding error callback, it will give you more ideas. Something like: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown{console.log(errorThrown);}

Comment: @Mosd, i added `callback: function(){console.log("stop")}` to ajax and put breakpoint into callback function but is it not triggered.

Comment: you mean you have: success: function (data) {
            ...} , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown{console.log(errorThrown);} ? the execution must go in either success or error callback (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), please confirm where is going

Comment: issue reporoduced only in Chrome browser, firefox, edge, opera - works nice...
tried to excute code in other PC and Chrome - works good..but not on my PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there isn't much information you have shared; here are some tips you could use to debug your problem based of assumptions where I think the problem is at.

1. debug your code by using a `console.log(data)` as the first thing in your code to make sure if you're accessing the right fields.
2. `data.status` is usually a status code `1xx`,`2xx`, `3xx`, `4xx` and `200` means the success of a request. I check if a response is successful like this `data.status == 200`, but you used `data.status == true` you should log the `data` to make sure you're using that correctly otherwise you'll always get a logged error.
3. `JSON.stringify(body)` will convert the body into a string and the `data` field of an `ajax` call takes an object with parameters to pass in its request. Is `JSON.stringify(body)` really what you meant to do or is it just `body`?

Well if you decide to add more information I'll be sure to update the answer with additional suspicions.

Comment: My server return reponse with `data.status` `true` or `false`

Comment: I tried make request from Microsoft Edge - all work fine but in Chroom I receive error...

Comment: @BogdanK what error is that? The one from the image?

Comment: I added image in question